# Socket.io is not sync with Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, sockets, redux, next.js, socket.io

I have a chat app similar to whatsapp web. The chat section shows all chats on the left and in the middle. By default when the user login the first contact is stored redux store as `selectedChatUser`.

I store all the chats sent to the user in the postgres db no matter if user is online or not. I have two events in the app: `send-msg` and receive-msg`.` send-msg`is emitted from frontend side and`receive-msg`is emitted from backend. I try to call the`getUserAllMessage()`to get all the chats from db whenever frontend detects`receive-msg` event detected from backend.

I don't know why when the `getUserAllMessage()` method is invoked by the `received-msg` event the `to` field gets empty which I directly get from the `selectedChatUser` store object. Here's my code:

ChatContainer.jsx:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getMessage } from "../../services/messageService";

function ChatContainer() {
  const loggedInUserEmail = useSelector(state=>state.loggedInUser.emailId);
  const selectedChatUser = useSelector(state=>state.selectedChatUser.selectedChatUser);
  const socket = useSelector(state=>state.socket.socket);
  const [userAllMessages, setUserAllMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!socket)return;
    socket.on('msg-receieved',async ()=>{
      console.log("message received: ",userAllMessages);
      await getUserAllMessage(); //problem arises here
    })
  },[socket])
  useEffect(()=>{
    getUserAllMessage();
  },[selectedChatUser])
  const getUserAllMessage = async ()=>{
    let payload = {
      from:loggedInUserEmail,
      to:selectedChatUser?.email   // IDK why this field gets empty even the selectedChatUser is set in redux store previously
    }
    try {
      const response = await getMessage(payload);      
      if(response.data.status === 200){
        console.log("user messages",response.data);
        setUserAllMessages(response.data.messages);
      }
      else{
        console.log("Error while getting user messages: ",response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
       console.log("Error while getting user messages: ",error);
    }
  }
  return <div className="overflow-auto custom-scrollbar relative w-full flex-grow h-full">
    <div className="bg-chat-background bg-fix h-full w-full absolute top-0 opacity-5 z-0"></div>
    <div className="mx-10 my-6  z-40">
    <div className="flex w-full">
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-end gap-1 w-full overflow-auto">
        {userAllMessages.map((message,index)=>(
          <div key={index}
          className={`flex ${message.senderId === loggedInUserEmail ? "justify-end":"justify-start"}`}
          >
              <div className={`text-white px-2 py-[5px] text-sm rounded-md flex gap-2 items-end max-w-[45%] ${message.senderId === selectedChatUser?.email ? "bg-input-background":"bg-outgoing-background"} `}>
                  <span className="break-all">{message?.message}</span>
              </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>;
}

export default ChatContainer;
```

ContactsList.jsx:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {setSelectedChatUser} from "../../store/chatSlice";
import {getAllContacts} from "../../services/userService";
import List from "./List";

function ContactsList() {
  const loggedInUser = useSelector(state=>state.loggedInUser.emailId);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [allUserContacts, setAllUserContacts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    getUserAllContactsList()
  },[])
  const getUserAllContactsList = async ()=>{
    let payload={
      email:loggedInUser
    }
    try {
      const response = await getAllContacts(payload);
      if(response.data.status === 200){
        console.log(response.data.users);
        setAllUserContacts(response.data.users)
        if(response.data.users?.length > 0){
          dispatch(setSelectedChatUser(response.data.users[0]));   //setting the first chat as the default selected chat user
        }
      }
      else{
        console.log("Error while fetching contacts: ",response.data)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error while fetching contacts: ",error);
    }
  }
  return <div className="bg-transparent max-h-screen overflow-auto">
    {allUserContacts.map((user,index)=>(
      <List key={index} profilePic={user?.image || '/avatars/1.png'} name={user.name} message={''} email={user.email} onClick={()=>dispatch(setSelectedChatUser(user))}/>
    ))}
  </div>;
}

export default ContactsList;
```

I don't know what happening with my code and why it's happening. It's my first time working with socket.io & redux. I have added comments where the problem is. If anyone knows where I have made the mistake please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you subscribe to the event `msg-receieved` it create a copy of function `getUserAllMessage()` and at that time your state `selectedChatUser` is empty ... so when you receive the event  `msg-receieved` and  `getUserAllMessage()` is called ,it has `selectedChatUser` empty ... try subscribing to `msg-received` event when you have `selectedChatUser` value .